# The name of my SQL linked server changed. I have a bunch of queries and stored procedures that use the old name. Is there anything I can do?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, linked-server

I have some code like this

```
    select *
    FROM [ServerName].[theserver].[dbo].[OrderWrappers]
```

My server name changed so now the above doesn't work and instead it would be

```
    select *
    FROM [NEWServerName].[theserver].[dbo].[OrderWrappers]
```

I access that table across lots of different places and many different jobs and stored procedures.

Is there anything I can do besides going into each stored procedure one my one and changing the code?

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes and no.

You will need to go through the code to change the code.  However, you can change the code to use [*synonyms*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-synonym-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) instead of hard-coded references.  Then, the *next* time you change the server, it will be pretty easy to update the code.

Or instead of synonyms, you could create a separate project with views to the tables on the remove server and use those views.  Those would also be simple to update.

Both of these methods, though, require modifying the existing code.  But they will help you write code for the future so you don't have this problem in the future.

Comment: Can the synonym is created with same name as old linked server? If yes, I think no changes would be required kn code right?

Comment: @ShamvilKazmi . . . That would be rather confusing and I would not recommend that approach.  But I think synonyms follow the same rules as other identifiers, so they can't replace multi-part names.